# Check BST using inorder

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree

I came across the following code to check a tree is BST or not.
**Please explain the purpose of using the prev pointer and the relation between root-data and prev->data.**

```
bool isBST(struct node* root) 
{ 
    static struct node *prev = NULL; 

    // traverse the tree in inorder fashion and keep track of prev node 
    if (root) 
    { 
        if (!isBST(root->left)) 
            return false; 

        // Allows only distinct valued nodes  
        if (prev != NULL && root->data <= prev->data) 
            return false; 

        prev = root; 

        return isBST(root->right); 
    } 

    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic definition of inorder traversal is

1. Traverse the left subtree, i.e., call Inorder(left-subtree)
2. Visit the root.
3. Traverse the right subtree, i.e., call Inorder(right-subtree)

Lets take an example of a BST.

[image: BST]

For the above tree the inorder traversal would be [2,5,6,8,10,13,15,19]. Basically Inorder traversal for a BST gives us the elements in **ascending order.**

So in your code, during the traversal the previous node is saved to compare it with current node. When compared, **the current node's data should be strictly greater than previous node's data** as traversal gives the ascending order. Thats why the below condition is used.

```
 if (prev != NULL && root->data <= prev->data) 
            return false;
```

If the current node's data (root->data) is less or equal to previous node's data (prev->data), then the tree is not a BST.